# Convert DataFrame columns to Objects efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Panda's DataFrame with a lot of entries. I would like to create an object by row without doing an iteration if possible.

Ie:

```
       Age   Name
       -----------
    0   13   John
    1   16   Marc
    2   17   Prisl
    3   14   Mike
    4   11   Robert
```

Is that possible? I found nothing on the documentation regarding this.

Comment: What do you mean by "create an object by row"? What object?

Comment: you want to construct an object  (probably containing a name and an age) for each row of the data frame without accessing each row? If so, how should that work? You have to move data around

Comment: I want to construct an object by row (Person with age and name) using the most efficient way to do it

Comment: What objects? and why do you want objects by the way?

Comment: I know this comes a little late, but I've updated my answer to the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a list of objects, you can use `itertuples`, these return `namedtuple` objects (well, almost).

```
list(df.itertuples(name='Person', index=False))

[Person(Age=13, Name='John'),
 Person(Age=16, Name='Marc'),
 Person(Age=17, Name='Prisl'),
 Person(Age=14, Name='Mike'),
 Person(Age=11, Name='Robert')]
```

---

Another idea uses `namedtuple` and `apply`.

```
from collections import namedtuple
cls = namedtuple(typename='Person', field_names=df.columns.tolist())

df.apply(lambda r: cls(**r.to_dict()), 1)

0      (13, John)
1      (16, Marc)
2     (17, Prisl)
3      (14, Mike)
4    (11, Robert)
dtype: object

df.apply(lambda r: cls(**r.to_dict()), 1).tolist()

[Person(Age=13, Name='John'),
 Person(Age=16, Name='Marc'),
 Person(Age=17, Name='Prisl'),
 Person(Age=14, Name='Mike'),
 Person(Age=11, Name='Robert')]
```

---

If you aren't particular on classes, you can use `to_dict` to return a list of records.

```
df.to_dict('records')

[{'Age': 13, 'Name': 'John'},
 {'Age': 16, 'Name': 'Marc'},
 {'Age': 17, 'Name': 'Prisl'},
 {'Age': 14, 'Name': 'Mike'},
 {'Age': 11, 'Name': 'Robert'}]
```