# Pool multiprocessing fail

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I'm doing a quite simple example of parallel work using 'Pool' from 'multiprocessing'. What I want to do is to launch many SQL queries at the same time.

I have activated the WAL mode to allow multiple read/write operations at the same time.

```
def FUNC1():        
    conn = sqlite3.connect("DB.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute(QUERY1)
    print "TEST"

    cur.close()  
    conn.close()
    return

def FUNC2():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("DB.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute(QUERY2)

    cur.close()  
    conn.close()

    return

if __name__ == '__main__':

    conn = sqlite3.connect("DB.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('PRAGMA journal_mode=wal')
    pool = Pool(processes=2)

    pool.map_async(FUNC1,"")
    pool.map_async(FUNC2,"")


    cur.close()
    conn.close()
```

The terminal should show a print : 'TEST' that will show that the routine has do the FUNC1 operation. The problem is that it shows nothing.

Does anyone knows why?

---

**EDIT**

I've changed the code (thank you 'mata'!) and now the problem is that there is no parallel work.

Actually the query takes 3 seconds to execute and If I pass three times the same query the final time is 9...

Why ?

```
def Query(Query):

    conn = sqlite3.connect("DB.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()

    curOperations.execute(Query)

    cur.close()
    conn.close()

    return


if __name__ == '__main__':

    conn = sqlite3.connect("DB.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute('PRAGMA journal_mode=wal')
    conn.commit()

    pool = Pool(processes=2)

    pool.map_async(Query,['QUERY1', 'QUERY2', 'QUERY3'])

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    cur.close()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: WAL mode concurrency has an effect only if you are using multiple connections.

Comment: And how can I stablish multiple connections? Should I connect to the database into each FUNC ?

Comment: If you don't mind, can you come to a resolution to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45816730/convert-dataframe-columns-to-objects-efficiently) please?

Comment: That appears to be the only way to ensure that each process gets its own connection. (In fact, SQLite [forbids using a connection over a fork](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q6), which is what `multiprocessing` uses.)

Comment: Ok, but even if I do that, the print (that indicates that the functions works) is not working

Comment: I added some new information and a new connection for each function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Pool.map_async()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map_async) calls a function once with each element of the supplied iterable as argument. You provide an empty iterable (empty string), so the function is never called. [`Pool.apply_async()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.apply_async) is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much ! :) It works but unfortunately there is no parallel work (if I pass three times the same query the time is 3x also)